# "becoming a doctor is not that important to me" vs. "for me"

Tags: prepositions

[A post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/22860/116345) gives good examples to distinguish "important to" and "important for"

1. "It is important for you to get well" ~ your life will be improved by returning to health
2. "It is important to your family that you get well" ~ they put a high value on you being healthy.

Apply those "rules" to the following example (adapted from [another related post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/118184/116345))

> Schoolwork is very important for Bob to become a doctor.

Which means Bob's life will be improved by becoming a doctor. Who could be the speaker? The common possibilities would be Bob's parents, Bob's friends, Bob himself.

What if Bob himself doesn't want to be a doctor? So, the situation becomes

> Bob's mother says: "Schoolwork is very **important** for Bob to become a doctor."

> Bob says to his best friend: "To be honest, becoming a doctor is not that **important to** me."

It is my understanding correct?

Comment: I think you are generally correct, except that _Schoolwork is very important for Bob to become a doctor_ means something like _If Bob is to become a doctor in the future, he needs to do well at school_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mostly agree with you, but I don't find

> Schoolwork is very important for Bob to become a doctor.

to be idiomatic, for the following reason.

*Important to* and *important for* are not grammatically parallel.

*To* introduces a complement of *important*, which tells you who regards the thing as important.

*For* is not syntactically linked to *important* at all: it is (an optional) part of the "to"-infinitive clause which may stand as subject of *important*:

> [To study] is important.

> [For Bob to study] is important.

Usually, this subject clause is moved to complement position, and the dummy subject *it* used:

> It is important [to study].

> It is important [for Bob to study].

but semantically, the clause is still the subject.

I don't find the example idiomatic because it is using a real subject ("Schoolwork"), so it's not clear what the grammatical role of the clause is.